# Wordpress 3.3 wp_list_pages link_before, link_after or child_of Issue

Tags: wordpress

I've recently upgraded wordpress to 3.3 version and the navigation is not working any more because I have spans tags into the menu link added with link_after and link_before.

Also `wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");` is not working but `wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");` is working. All I need is the the submenu for the parent list.

Any ideas?

Comment: The first wp_list_pages call would work for top-level pages, the second for sub-pages. WordPress docs recommend an if statement for checking whether you're on the sub-page or not http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

As for the issue about nav not working, can you post a code example? wp_list_pages still seems to take both the link_after and link_before params, so that should be working...

Comment: Thanks for your comment... I noticed that I have this problem when I have this too: <code>function add_markup_pages($output) {
    $output= preg_replace('/page-item/', ' first-page-item page-item', $output, 1);
$output=substr_replace($output, " last-page-item page-item", strripos($output, "page-item"), strlen("page-item"));
    return $output;
}
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'add_markup_pages');</code>. I need this classes ( first-page-item and last-page-item ) to style the top lists. So if I have this added the top navigation doesn't display nothing.

Comment: There is displayed just "first-page-item last-page-item" and no list with links. But if I remove this line <code>$output=substr_replace($output, " last-page-item page-item", strripos($output, "page-item"), strlen("page-item"));</code> then it's working. The menu is displayed. This is happening only in WP 3.3

Comment: I had a similar problem. My solution was to change the code to use "nicer" PHP (see the documentation of the functiom, use array args instead of the & for arguments), and to change the argument values not to use " in the value... Gladly, this solved the problem. In case any help is needed, you are welcome to contact me - shushu.i@gmail.com